# meta tags don't display when not authenticated

Tags: meta-tags

I'm using Drupal 7, Meta Tags/Open Graph meta tags 7.x-1.0-alpha6.

When logged in, meta tags act as I would expect. I see the meta tags when I view the page source.

When not logged in, the meta tags are missing. What could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

You have a patch for this issue. There is a README.txt file updated.

All you need to do is to render meta tags in your `page--front.tpl.php`, add following in this file of your theme:

```
<?php
 render($page['content']['metatags']); 
?>
```

Or you can try to add this in your `template.php` file of the theme:

```
<?php
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (!empty($vars['is_front'])) {
    metatag_page_build($vars['page']);
  }
}
?>
```

Just replace `THEMENAME` with the name of your theme.

Comment: THEMENAME_preprocess_page worked!

Answer (score 0):

Check metatags permissions, be sure the anynomous user has the right permission to access metatags